# Odd Hard Drive Serial Number in Powershell

Tags: powershell, hard-drive, serial-number

When I use that command: Get-WMIObject win32_physicalmedia | Select-Object SerialNumber I get different serial number of my hard drive.

It shows 8CE3_8E05_0053_5038 and it should show Z03F7BQ7F2F3

Did some of you had similar issue?

I thought it is in 16 bit coding but after changing it to 10bit it didn't match.

Comment: So, where did you get the `Z03F7BQ7F2F3` from?

Comment: It pretty much depends on the manufacturer and how they implement the HWID.
I have 3 drives and only one shows the manufacturer's serial when running that command.